# My layout gets messy whenever I open it in the emulator (It's a background image with textviews)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, background, android-studio

For my project I'm using background images,so I can put invisible buttons..
but the problem is when I open the activity in the emulator,it just turns out to be a salad( Text views mixed with buttons etc..)

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/firstname"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lastname"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lastname" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lastname"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstname"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lastname"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lastname"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lastname" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewUser"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewUser" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:entries="@array/choose"
    android:prompt="@string/genders"
    android:layout_below="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/confirmPasswordEditText" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/joinus"
    android:id="@+id/signUpButton"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewUser"
    android:layout_below="@+id/age"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/email" />
```

Comment: Please post your android xml layout code and some screenshots as to what exactly your problem is!

Comment: Are you using ImageViews AND TextViews together? Or just TextViews with a background image?

Comment: welcome to multiple screen support, it must be relative layout cooking for you :)...

Comment: @Antrromet I tried to,but my reputation is barely 1.that's why I can't post images. but you can give me your email,if you are willing to help.. Also,I have more than one layout that has this problem. One is textviews with buttons and the other is just buttons.but the thing is no matter what widgets they are,they never stay in their supposed place!

Comment: @Lady_ari  I have more than one layout that has this problem. One is textviews with buttons with a background and the other is just buttons also with background.but the thing is no matter what widgets they are,they never stay in their supposed place!

Comment: @PankajNimgade Yes it is:(

Comment: Can you copy and paste your xml code into the question at least?

Comment: @Yasmin12, I have posted my answer, although it's nit related to your current layout, it will solve the issue you have and things you might face in future

Comment: @PankajNimgade I'm trying my best to understand it,but thank youu:) appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yasmin12, Hi there, I can understand what has happened here, in your layout "dp" is causing problem. Use "dip" instead they will help you in debugging your layout as they will try to keep a coherent size to multiple screen resolutions,

```
               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avtar_animation_11"
                android:layout_width="45dip"
                android:layout_height="45dip"
                android:src="@drawable/avtar011"/>
```

while supporting multiple screen when you give "dp" to dimensions, Actually android expects you to provide different values for different screen resolution. Lets say below is your imagview dimensions make few folders in res folder in your android project like these below

[image]

`values-hdpi`,
`values-mdpi`,
`values-ldpi`,
`values-xhdpi`,
`values-xxhdpi`

and in them make a `dimens.xml` file each of them and write

```
<dimen name="image_view_width">28dp</dimen>
<dimen name="image_view_height">28dp</dimen>
```

now that i have mentioned "dp" here instead of dip android wants me to keep track for different dimensions for different screen resolution, So i will change the image_view_width and image_view_height values are in separate values folders where `dimens.xml` is located. Make sure your dp values change as per your screen resolution you want your view to fit in.

```
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avtar_animation_11"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/image_view_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_view_height"
            android:src="@drawable/avtar011"/>
```

hard part is over now android will pick one of `dimens.xml` values depending on which screen your app is running, Voila now your layout rocks

Comment: @Yasmin12, kindly change the dimensions of mage_view_width and image_view_height in dimens.xml file in every type of values-(****) folder, give 30dp for height and width in dimens.xml in values-ldpi. give 50dp for height and width in dimens.xml in values-mdpi.  give 60dp for height and width in dimens.xml in values-hdpi.  give 70dp for height and width in dimens.xml in values-xhdpi.  give 80dp for height and width in dimens.xml in values-xxhdpi. fow try to check the preview for all type's of layout at once and you will see that different layout resolution with have different height and width.

Answer (score 1):

Ok from what I can see, you're using the layout id incorrectly.

For example, you've got :

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewUser"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewUser" />
```

The line that says

```
android:layout_alignbottom="@+id/spinner"
```

should be replaced with

```
android:layout_alignbottom="@id/spinner"
```

WITHOUT the '+' symbol.

That way, you're referencing another layout versus defining an id value.

**EDIT**
Here is an example of what the view should look like to avoid xml errors:

```
<!-- This is the top-left-most layout in the view -->
<EditText
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/age" />

<!-- This layout will be shown BELOW the 'age' layout -->
<EditText
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_below="@id/age" />

<!-- This layout will be shown TO THE RIGHT OF the 'age' layout -->
<EditText
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/birthday"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/age" />
```

Now, if you try to reference `@id/birthday` in the `@id/age` EditText view, you'll get an error, because the layout doesn't know about `@id/birthday` yet. It is defined BELOW `@id/age`.

Does this make sense?

Comment: well I removed the +. but it just got worse.

Comment: Right, because before you can reference a view with `@id/`, that view has to be defined. Are you seeing errors? Or the actual layout got worse?

Comment: Ok, pick one of the views to be the "anchor" view which all other base themselves off of. Usually, I set it to be the top-left-most view. Make sure that view does NOT reference any other layouts ('below', 'toRightOf', etc). Then start basing the other views off of that one. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks..I'll be waiting

Comment: And I'm not quite sure why the other guy's answer was marked correct as it doesn't really solve your issue.