# layout change when run on other mobile

Tags: android, xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#fff">

        <!--  Header  Starts-->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip">
            <!-- Logo Start-->
            <TextView
                android:text="Driver Info "
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
            <!-- Logo Ends -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--  Header Ends -->
        <!-- Footer Start -->

        <!-- Footer Ends -->

        <!-- Registration Form -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/r1"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="3"

            android:layout_below="@id/header">

            <Button android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_style"
                android:text="Upload Licence copy"
                android:layout_weight="1
                "/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_style"
                android:layout_weight="1
                "
                android:text="Upload Licence copy"/>
            <!-- Full Name Label -->

            <!--  Email Label -->

            <!-- Password Label -->
            <!--Mobile edittex-->
            <!--age lable-->
            <!-- Register Button -->

            <!-- Link to Login Screen -->


        </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/r1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pic"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"

    android:weightSum="1"
    >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_below="@+id/r1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:maxWidth="42dp"
            android:maxHeight="42dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"



            android:src="@drawable/lincense"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_below="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="42dp"
        android:maxHeight="42dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"


        android:src="@drawable/lincense"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4" />


</LinearLayout>

        <Button android:id="@+id/signup"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

            android:background="@drawable/btn_style"

                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Complete the process"/>

        <!-- Registration Form Ends -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

when i select other device and check my layout its show this as i mentioned in image. any body have any idea how to make it for every device. what is the best solution for this . . i have tried many thing . . but did not sort out that

Comment: and how it should look like??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep Android Layout consistent across various devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338270/how-to-keep-android-layout-consistent-across-various-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this on manifest:

```
<supports-screens 
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />
```

Or you can try this links:

[Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

[Supporting Different Densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)